# Data types from csv columns using sed and regex

Tags: bash, sed

I have to resolve a problem for the university. I have to use a bash script to indicate the type of data of each column in a csv.

This is the header and the 1st line of the csv

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
2022S000001;01/01/2022;1:30:00;AVDA. ALBUFERA, 19;19;13;PUENTE DE VALLECAS;Alcance;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De 18 a 30 años;Mujer;NULL;NULL;443359,226;4472082,272;N;NULL
```

I am using a sed command to determine the type of data:

```
sed -rn '1p
    2s/[[:blank:]]//g
    2s/([[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+)/(time)/g
    2s/([[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+)/(date)/g
    2s/([[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+)/(decimal)/g
    2s/([[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+)/(string)/g
    2s/([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+,[0-9]+)/(string)/g
    2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/gp' < $file
```

But not all the fields are populated with the right type of data. This is the output I get

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
(string);(date);(time);(string);(int);(int);PUENTEDEVALLECAS;Alcance;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De(string)años;Mujer;NULL;NULL;(decimal);(decimal);N;NULL
```

How can I make the bold fields are replace with (string)

I have used:

```
2s/([^(string)][a-zA-Z]+)/(string)/g
```

But the output is totally wrong

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
(string);((string));(ti(string));(string);(int);(int)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string)(string);((string));((string))(string)(string)
```

The expected output is:

```
(string);(date);(time);(string);(int);(int);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(decimal);(decimal);(string);(string)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please review [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and update the question with proper formatting (also remove the bold indicators from the data); please update the question to show the (correct) expected output; a few more  questions ... do you need to determine the datatype for every field in *every* line or just the first data line?  are you limited to `sed` or are you open to other tools (eg, `awk`)? if `awk` is an option, what version of `awk` (`awk --version`) is on your system? can you have 2 different datatypes in the same field (eg, string + int, date + time)?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the expected output, hope it's better now. About your questions: I only have to determine the data type for the first data line. Awk is a valid option, I am using 5.0.1. and I can only have one data type per field.

Comment: what is the format of the dates ... `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: What should be printed as the type of a field that doesn't match any of your regexps?

Comment: Format of the date is DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: I have always to deliver a data type, the expected outcome is available. I could add Boolean as another data type but it's not required so I prefer to simplify with string

Comment: So then should the logic be that if a field isn't a date, time, decimal, or int it must be a string?

Comment: Exactly, you're right! Whatever is not a date, time, decimal or int, should be flagged as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Awk` will be a better choice as it can easily split the line into fields
to examine the fields one by one:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '
    NR>1 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            if (sub(/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/, "(time)", $i));
            else if (sub(/^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$/, "(date)", $i));
            else if (sub(/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/, "(decimal)", $i));
            else if (sub(/^[0-9]+$/, "(int)", $i));
            else if (sub(/^.*[a-zA-Z].*$/, "(string)", $i));
        }
    }
1' input_file
```

Output:

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorologico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
(string);(date);(time);(string);(int);(int);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(string);(decimal);(decimal);(string);(string)
```

The `if .. else ..` syntax will be necessary; otherwise once replaced string,
such as `(time)`, may be replaced by `(string)` again.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for pointing it out. It is a typo and corrected. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I suspect that final `if (sub(/^.*[a-zA-Z].*$/, "(string)", $i))` could be replaced with just `$i="(string)"` because what else could it be given the "type"s the OP has available but we'll see what the OP says.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the comment. I was also thinking as you suggest, but intentionally left the regex condition for the string, considering some exceptions (other types), such as blank, special characters only, etc. It will depend on the OP's definition.

Comment: I've asked again for clarity on that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178115/data-types-from-csv-columns-using-sed-and-regex/72178995?noredirect=1#comment127545185_72178115

Comment: Hello, I have tried your code and it's not working as it should. I have to print the header and apply the code to the 2nd line of the CSV, however, your code is applied to all lines in the CSV, and the output generated is more than 10k lines, as this is the size of the CSV. I tried replacing NR>1 with NR==2, NR ==1, NR<2, NR<1, and it's not even providing the expected output either ```2022S010478;15/03/2022;10:50:00;AVDA. ANDALUCIA / AVDA. SAN FERMIN;1;12;USERA;Otro;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De 18 a 30 años;Mujer;14;Sin asistencia sanitaria;441049,881;4469122,264;N;NULL
```

Comment: I have found out how to fix the last remark. Last line should be like this ```NR==3 {exit} 1' $file```and it works as expected. Many thanks!